# How to Integrating Source tree with Spring tool suite

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, atlassian-sourcetree

I just want to use source tree which installed on windows machine . But my requirement is to integrate source tree into spring tool suite and need to access source tree from STS ..

How do i do that .. any help Appreciate.

Comment: Is this https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ what you mean by 'sourcetree'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source-tree seems to be a standalone Windows app that functions as a client for git or mercurial. So I don't think you can 'integrate' STS or Eclipse with sourcetree. However...

Eclipse and STS already has tooling for 'git' called 'egit' which is installed by default. So if you are using git, then there is nothing to do as Eclipse 'egit' already provides git integration. Egit works fairly well and I use it myself.

For Mercurial there are also integration options available. For example:
[MercurialEclipse](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Home). You can install these on top of STS (or Eclipse). I don't know how good it is as I haven't used it myself. You can also do a [google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=eclipse%20mercurial) to try and find more Eclipse plugins that support Mercurial.